# Ошибка при выполнении команды flutter pub get "Cannot create link.. errno = 1314"

Tags: flutter

Экспериментально установлено, что ругается на пакет - objectbox_generator: ^1.2.0
Полный текст сообщение:
Cannot create link, path = 'C:\Users\Pawel\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache_temp\dirc2e1a3d4\integration-tests\basics\pubspec.yaml' (OS Error: Клиент не обладает требуемыми правами.
, errno = 1314)
pub get failed (66; , errno = 1314))

Может кто сталкивался, как исправить?

Comment: Приложите `flutter doctor -v`

Comment: Это распространенная проблема из-за корявости винды. Что может помочь: 1. запуск процесса (выполняющего `pub get`) с элевацией, т.е. от имени админа; 2. перенос проекта на диск `C:`, если сейчас он на другом диске; 3. исправление ACL утилитами предназначенными для этого; 4. `flutter pub cache [repair|clean]` или полная очистка кэша паба вручную, удалением директории; 5. переход на *nix :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Жмёте правой кнопкой мыши по коренной папке проекта (самая верхняя)
2. Выбираете Copy path -> absolute path
3. Открываете проводник, переходите в скопированный путь
4. В левом правом углу проводника "Файл" -> Запустить Windows Power Shell от имени администратора
5. Вводите flutter pub get